# Mutating self in enum method

Tags: enums, rust, self

This is cobbled together to illustrate the problem that I have with the `switch` function. I do not have problem printing "Left" "Right" endlessly.

The point of `switch` is to swap the value of enum to another. This solution doesn't work because presumably the `switch` moves `t` into itself so it's no longer usable. Use of mutable references causes a whole host of other problems, like with lifetime and mismatched types. The documentation had instructions how to do this with structs, but not enums. The compiler suggested implementing `Copy` and `Clone` to the enum, but that did nothing useful.

How is this type of method supposed to be made in Rust?

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = Dir::Left;

    loop {
        match &t {
            &Dir::Left => println!("Left"),
            &Dir::Right => println!("Right"),
        }

        t.switch();
    }
}

enum Dir {
    Left,
    Right,
}

impl Dir {
    //this function is the problem here
    fn switch(mut self) {
        match self {
            Dir::Left => self = Dir::Right,
            Dir::Right => self = Dir::Left,
        };
    }
}
```

Of course I could just make it so

```
t = t.switch();
```

and

```
fn switch(mut self) -> Self {
    match self {
        Dir::Left  => return Dir::Right,
        Dir::Right => return Dir::Left,
    };
}
```

But I feel that would be comparatively clumsy solution, and I would like to avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your method consumes your data instead of borrowing it. If you borrow it, it works fine:

```
impl Dir {
    fn switch(&mut self) {
        *self = match *self {
            Dir::Left => Dir::Right,
            Dir::Right => Dir::Left,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think to use raw pointers. Why borrowing with `*` works fine but `&` creates unholy mess?

Comment: @Ritielko You need to (re)read the basis in the Rust book. In Rust, all the things are owned by a scope, and you can either give them to another scope or you can lend them (*i.e.* they are borrowed), just like your personal belongings: you can give them to someone or lend them to a friend. `&` means that the ownership is not transferred.

Comment: @Ritielko Related chapter: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html